# How to export private key? (GnuPG)

Tags: terminal, public-key, rsa, gpg, private-key

I have successfully created GnuPG public/private key pair using RSA and RSA algorithm. How can I export a public key and private key in the form of file with the `.asc` extension?

Comment: Note: recently gpg2 came out. Some distros (debian) use exclusively this, others (ubuntu) use still the first version on gpg and the 2 on gpg2. They seem compatible with the public keys but not with the private ones.

Answer (score 12):

Hint 1: gpg **calls private keys 'secret'** because PGP dates from before people settled on the names 'private' key for the half of an asymmetric pair held by (ideally) only one party versus 'secret' key for a symmetric value usually held by two or more mutually trusting parties but nobody else.

`man gpg2 | less "+/export-secret"` then `n` (go to second match) shows:

```
   --export-secret-keys

   --export-secret-subkeys
          Same  as --export, but exports the secret keys instead.  This is
          normally not very useful and a security risk.  The  second  form
          of  the  command  has  the special property to render the secret
          part of the primary key useless; this  is  a  GNU  extension  to
          OpenPGP  and  other  implementations can not be expected to suc-
          cessfully import such a key.  See the option  --simple-sk-check-
          sum  if  you  want  to import such an exported key with an older
          OpenPGP implementation.
```

Hint 2: you can output to a file by just redirecting, or using (either of)

```
   --output file

   -o file
          Write output to file.
```

However, people usually use the `.asc` extension for files in 'ASCII armor(ed)' format, which is base64 with dashes-BEGIN and dashes-END lines and sometimes (including here) 822/MIME-style headers. If you want not just a file *named* `.asc`, but a file in the **usual `.asc` format**, use (either of)

```
   --armor

   -a     Create ASCII armored output.   The  default  is  to  create  the
          binary OpenPGP format.
```

**TLDR:**

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys -a -o file.asc [keyid ...]
```